# Tigervncserver won't start without sudo

Tags: xfce, vnc

Running Xubuntu 22.04

Trying to run vncserver (on startup but baby steps first).

The following exit:

```
tigervncserver :1 
tigervncserver -localhost no
tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xfce4-session
```

The following work OK

```
sudo tigervncserver
tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
```

Tried with/without xstartup file:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4
```

Tried deleting all .Xauthority* files in $HOME
Tried deleting .vnc from $HOME

Using only command with xsession file:

```
vncserver
>session startup via '/home/me/.vnc/xstartup' exited with status 1!
```

Using vncserver without xsession file:

```
vncserver
>X connection to :2 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
>Session startup via '/etc/X11/Xtigervnc-session' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating an ~/.vnc/xstartup file with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/usr/bin/startxfce4
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
x-window-manager &
```